# How to avoid code duplication caused by javascript dict access?

Tags: javascript

I have two functions that group a list of dicts according to the value of a certain key. Here's how my array looks:

```js
const sections = [
  {
    file_id: '1',
    heading_level: 4,
    readme_file_name: 'Quick.Quick.md',
    section_codes: [
      1,
      3,
    ],
    section_id: '1',
    title: 'Nimble',
  },
  {
    file_id: '1',
    heading_level: 2,
    readme_file_name: 'Quick.Quick.md',
    section_codes: [
      3,
      4,
    ],
    section_id: '2',
    title: 'Swift Version',
  },
  // ...
];
```

Some times I need to group the sections by it's `heading_level` key value, and other times I need to group by the first value on `section_codes` array.

I've created a single function for each grouping, but the code is exactly the same, except for the line where I access the desired key. So I've tried removing duplication, and here's where I've gotten so far:

```js
// Helper func
function getValueForKey(key, section) {
  const originalValue = section[key];

  if (Array.isArray(originalValue)) {
    return originalValue[0];
  }

  return originalValue;
}

export function groupSectionsByKey(key, sections) {
  const groupedSections = {};

  sections.forEach((section) => {
    const groupKey = getValueForKey(key, section);
    const codeArray = groupedSections[groupKey];

    if (codeArray) {
      codeArray.push(section);
    } else {
      groupedSections[groupKey] = [section];
    }
  });

  return groupedSections;
}
```

This `getValueForKey` function seems a bit off for me, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this. Does anyone have some feedback?

Thanks.

Comment: Secondly you can pass function to your function to make it more customizable. And first of all use lodash or underscore and change your imperative style to functional. Everything you are looking for was already implemented.

Comment: @TomaszMaciejewski thanks for the reply. Do you mean letting whoever calls `getValueForKey` pass it's own implementation of `getValueForKey` as parameter? Also, could give me some concrete examples of how loads and underscore solve this problem, as I am not familiar with them? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, they should be able to pass their own implementation. `groupSectionsByKey(function(section) {return section.section_codes[0];}, sections)` and then you just call `key(section)` to get the key.

Comment: I would suggest that you have a look at the implementation suggested on this SO question regarding how to implement a 'groupBy' method - might suffice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 1):

Solution using lodash, I really recommend to read docs of this valuable library https://lodash.com. In addition to this please read about functional style in JS as it creates much more concise and readable solution in most cases.

```
const { groupBy } = require('lodash');

const sections = [
    {
      file_id: '1',
      heading_level: 4,
      readme_file_name: 'Quick.Quick.md',
      section_codes: [
        1,
        3,
      ],
      section_id: '1',
      title: 'Nimble',
    },
    {
      file_id: '1',
      heading_level: 2,
      readme_file_name: 'Quick.Quick.md',
      section_codes: [
        3,
        4,
      ],
      section_id: '2',
      title: 'Swift Version',
    },
    // ...
  ];

  const groupSectionsByKey = (sections, key) => groupBy(sections, (section) => Array.isArray(section[key]) ? section[key][0] : section[key]);
  const sectionsGroupedByCode = groupSectionsByKey(sections, "section_codes"); //example execution with section_codes
  console.log(sectionsGroupedByCode );
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the example. So it seems like I wasn't very off. From what I understood, if I add a function parameter to my `groupSectionsByKey` letting the caller specify how the key should be accessed, then I'd have the same behavior as lodash.

Comment: The difference is significant - in functional style which is a type of declarative paradigm you only say 'what' not 'how'. You can try as an exercise add some more processing e.g. groupBy section but only if title is X and collect the heading level using both your previous approach and lodash.

Comment: I don't think you need a `groupSectionsByKey` any more. Just use `groupBy(sections, (section) => sections.section_codes[0]);`

Comment: @immibis groupSectionsByKey is generic function which allows to pass the key by which you group by, so that you don't need to repeat the same code with heading_level, title, etc.

Comment: @TomaszMaciejewski Yeah, but groupBy also allows you to pass the key by which you group by. It's the second parameter and it can be any expression, instead of having to be a field name.